# Find $\alpha$ from trigonometric equation...

Tags: trigonometry

I have this equation I don't know how to get quadriatic equation with tangent...

$\ 1.77 = 4 \tan[\alpha] - 0.7848/\cos[\alpha]^2$ I should get this
$\ 157 \tan[\alpha]^2- 800\tan[\alpha]+511= 0$

Comment: What is $\cos[\alpha]^2$? Is it $\cos^2\alpha$ or $\cos(\alpha^2)$?

Comment: The numbers don't quite seem to work out, but $\frac{1}{\cos^2\alpha} = \sec^2\alpha = 1+\tan^2\alpha$.

Answer (score 0):

Use the identity
$$
\frac{1}{cos^2 \alpha} = 1 + \tan^2 \alpha
$$
to write
$$
1.77 = 4\tan\alpha - 0.7848 \tan^2 \alpha - 0.7848 \\
 0.7848 \tan^2 \alpha - 4\tan\alpha + 2.5548 = 0
$$
and multiply that whole equation by 200 to get something really close to your desired equation.

Answer (score 0):

Starting from Mark Fischler's answer, I should start multiplying every term by 10,000 to get rid of the decimal numbers. This will give (setting $x=\tan(\alpha)$) $$7848x^2-40000x+25548=0$$ Now, divide each coefficient by $50$ in order to transform $40000$ to $800$ and simplify the fractions since numerators and denominators are even numbers. So, you should arrive to $$\frac{3924 x^2}{25}-800 x+\frac{12774}{25}=0$$ Convertind to decimal, this last expression write $$156.96 x^2-800. x+510.96$$ very close to what you are looking for.

However, you must take care about the impact of rounding coefficients when you have to compute the roots. For the exact equation, the roots are $$x_{\pm}=\frac{5000\pm\sqrt{12468706}}{1962}$$ which are $$\{\{x\to 0.748672022110895\},\{x\to 4.34816793711439\}\}$$ while for the equation in which coefficients have been rounded, the roots are$$x_{\pm}=\frac{400\pm\sqrt{79773}}{157}$$ which are $$\{\{x\to 0.748782520308800\},\{x\to 4.34675888096509\}\}$$ So, this rounding puts errors at the level of the fourth significant digit.

Any way, you have the $x$'s from which you compute now the corresponding $\alpha$'s.